# How does one verify the encryption done by QLDB internally?

Tags: amazon-web-services, encryption

As mentioned in QLDB Documentation that all data in transit and at rest is encrypted. How one can verify or validate that the encryption is done by QLDB internally.

Comment: Can you post some of the code you have tried and elaborate on the question a little?

Comment: [AWS Artifact - Amazon Web Services (AWS)](https://aws.amazon.com/artifact/)

Comment: I don't have any code as such. But i want to test that the encryption is done by QLDB internally as per the AWS Documentation.